# Tesseract Extract specific information

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I would like to scan this image and get only the Name and City information from the image. How should I get this information ?

I am using tesseract 3.02.[image: sample image]

There will hundreds of images which I have to process and extract only specific information (say name and city) from it.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question?

Comment: No but I solved it , as for me all my images were kind of same ( templatized e.g. a KYC form). As mine was a web application, I used Jquery Crop to get X,Y, height and width co-ordinates of the image and then used tesseract to scan only that portion based x,y,height and width co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It would all depend on which Tesseract SDK you are using of course. I used the open source G8Tesseract [iOS SDK](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS) for a project that did something similar to what you are trying to do. If you are using that framework this may be help. What I recommend is that when you create your `G8RecognitionOperation`, there is a method you call to retrieve the data called `recognitionCompleteBlock`. Within the completion block of this method grab the result of the operation and iterate through and parse the data that you'd like. Since you know that the information you want is just after "Name" / right before "Social security", I would slice all the unwanted text before and after that and then dissect from there. Something like this:

```
 G8RecognitionOperation *operation = [[G8RecognitionOperation alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
// Set up operation...

operation.recognitionCompleteBlock = ^(G8Tesseract *tesseract) {
    // Fetch the recognized text
    NSString *recognizedText = tesseract.recognizedText;

    NSLog(@"%@", recognizedText);

    // GET NAME
    // Split the result into two strings / Index 0 is trash because it is before Name
    NSArray *slice1 = [recognizedText componentsSeparatedByString:@"Name"];
    NSString *slice1String = slice1[1];

    // What comes before "Social" should be the name you are looking for
    NSArray *slice2 = [slice1String componentsSeparatedByString:@"Social"];
    NSString *name = slice2[0];

    //GET CITY (do the same thing here)
    // Split the rest of the result and get the desired data
    NSArray *slice3 = [slice2[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"City"];
    NSString *slice3String = slice3[1];

    // What comes before "State" should be the city you are looking for
    NSArray *slice4 = [slice3String componentsSeparatedByString:@"State"];
    NSString *city = slice4[0];

    NSLog(@"Applicant Name: %@ | City: %@",name, city);

};
```

Comment: any other open source sdk available, which does this functionality ?

Comment: What platform are you trying to run this on? There are a few out there I know of. https://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/ is a .NET wrapper. Plus https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/ is a Python API. Whatever platform you are going to build for, you probably have a solution out there.

Comment: Do keep in mind one thing though. In my experience Tesseract does really well at recognizing printed characters on a nicely scanned page. It does not do so well in the human hand written department. And if you have someone with awful handwriting, your results will be deplorable.

Comment: I am trying to build on java platform and all the images are printed ones.